# how to create Ec2 instance using just javascript code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I wanted to create a ec2 instance on click of button using javascript I need a new Amazon EC2 instance

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: [CloudFormation Template is one way to Go](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html)

Comment: AWS Cloudformation Service provides an efficient way of launching resources through JSON or YAML. You can do it by creating a template and then placing your JSON code in it.
In fact, you can simply drag and drop required resources from resource type, this will provide preconfigured code with minimal changes required.